# Not able to flash android N preview system.img in Nexus 6P

Tags: fastboot, nexus-6p, 7.0-nougat

*Not able to flash android N preview system.img in Nexus 6P*

**Android N preview** (Nexus 6P "angler")

**Build** : angler-npd56n-factory-1ce5ccad.tgz

1. fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-angler-angler--03.55.img
2. fastboot reboot-bootloader
3. fastboot flash radio radio-angler-angler-03.67.img
4. fastboot reboot-bootloader
5. fastboot erase system
6. fastboot erase boot
7. fastboot erase recovery
8. fastboot erase cache
9. fastboot flash system system.img

   - **error: cannot load 'system.img'**
10. fastboot flash boot boot.img
11. fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
12. fastboot flash cache cache.img
13. fastboot flash vendor vendor.img
14. fastboot reboot

***Already tried below options***

- *fastboot -S 512M flash system system.img*
- *fastboot -S 1024M flash system system.img*
- *fastboot -S 2048M flash system system.img*

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with the system.img file. Could the download have been corrupted?

Comment: same commands working for build : 6.0.1 (MTC19V)  from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#sojus

Comment: It's probably not the command. Bet it's something that's to do with the system.img itself. Did you do a md5 checksum verification on what's available on the download page vs what you have?

Comment: Verified checksum, it is still not working.